# Shortcut key to send new Messages.app text

Tags: macos, messages, notifications, widgets

I was wondering if there is a way to have a system wide shortcut key to display Messages.app with the "New Message" window open so that I can quickly send messages.

Something like the little popup in Notifications sidebar would be perfect! See screenshot!

[image]

Comment: Slightly different problem, but answers might help: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/77633/new-email-message-with-a-global-keyboard-shortcut?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I use a Quicksilver Trigger to open Messages, and since I always have the main Messages window open I just use ⌘N to create a new message. Not a one stop solution, but I use it constantly at work.